# Initialize smooks by reading files from remote location

Tags: java, smooks

I am trying to read smooks from remote location my code is :

```
    public Smooks createSmooks() throws Exception {             
        Smooks smooks = new Smooks("\\\\qa01\\conf\\order\\realec\\outbound.xml");
        return smooks;
     }
```

But it is giving following exception :

```
 java.io.IOException: Failed to access data stream for resource 
 [qa01/conf/order/realec/outbound.xml]. Tried filesystem, classpath and URL.
```

Previously, these files were placed with in jar. So I had no issues by reading it in such a way:

```
 public Smooks createSmooks() {
  Smooks smooks = new Smooks("./conf/order/realec/outbound.xml");
  return smooks;
 }
```

Can you please help me creating smooks object for files placed at some remote location?

Comment: This code won't compile because you're missing at least a double quote. Furthermore you have to escape `\\` properly in your path at your first piece of code.

Comment: I am sorry, copied the uncompiled code.

Below is the actual code

public Smooks createSmooks() throws Exception {             
     Smooks smooks = new Smooks("\\\\qa01\\conf\\order\\realec\\outbound.xml");
     return smooks;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I assume the file you're reading is a smooks config file.  In any case, you should be able to open an InputStream to the remote config and then provide that to the Smooks constructor.